# How do I use an index to reference an item in an array using express + react

Tags: reactjs, express

I am creating an express + react website that allows the user to add, edit and delete an item from their web projects which is an array which is saved in my express backend. I have the add functionality working but I am unsure on how to reference which item I want deleted. The idea is that the user just presses the button associated with the webproject and then the backend uses the index of the item in the array to delete the item. I do not know how to reference the index number in my backend logic. I feel that I will be able to link it to the frontend once I can get the backend to work

```
server.js(Backend file)
let webProjects = [
  {
    TITLE: "React Game",
    DESCRIPTION: "Tic tac toe game created using Create React App",
    URL: "http://someURL/myapp/game/",
  },
  {
    TITLE: "Online Store",
    DESCRIPTION: "Online store created with HTML, CSS and Javascript.",
    URL: "http://someURL2/shop/index",
  },
  {
    TITLE: "Online Store",
    DESCRIPTION: "Online store created with HTML, CSS and Angular.",
    URL: "http://someURL3/shop2/index",
  },
];


App.js

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Display from "./components/Display";
import Header from "./components/Header";

function App() {
  //We set the content as the webprojects using useState so that it can be manipulated later on
  const [content, setContent] = useState({ webProjects: [] });

  //This is the state components that will be passed down as props to the Header and then to 
the Add Modal
  const [addID, setAddID] = useState("");
  const [addTITLE, setAddTITLE] = useState("");
  const [addDESCRIPTION, setAddDESCRIPTION] = useState("");
  const [addURL, setAddURL] = useState("");




  //This is the useEffect which GET's all of the webprojects that are currently in the array
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      }
    }).then((response) => response.json()
    ).then((response) => {setContent(response)}
    )
  }, [])

  function updateState(data) {
    setContent(data)
  }



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header 
        addID={addID}
        setAddID={setAddID}
        addTITLE={addTITLE}
        setAddTITLE={setAddTITLE}
        addDESCRIPTION={addDESCRIPTION}
        setAddDESCRIPTION={setAddDESCRIPTION}
        addURL={addURL}
        setAddURL={setAddURL}
        updateState={updateState}
       // getChange={getChange}
      />
      <Display 
        projectData={content.webProjects}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;








Display.js
import React from 'react'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const Display = ({projectData}) => {

  const handleDelete = () => {

    fetch("/api/:index", {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: {
    
      },
  })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
         console.log(response)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap displayCard justify-center">
        {projectData.map((projectData, index) => (
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={index}>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{projectData.TITLE}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
              Description: {projectData.DESCRIPTION}
              </Card.Text>
              <Card.Text>
                 URL: {projectData.URL}
               </Card.Text>
              <Card.Link ><Button>edit</Button></Card.Link>
              <Card.Link ><Button>Delete</Button></Card.Link>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default Display
```

Comment: Don't use the item index.  Use a unique identifier for the item.  If `TITLE` or `URL` are guaranteed to be unique, you can use either of those.  Otherwise, create a unique `ID` (number, guid, etc.) and use that.

Comment: Hi @freddykruger75, in your sample database (server.js) file, you can add a unique id/key field to while creating new record and then you can refer the same id whenever you do any CRUD(Create, read, update, Delete) operations. Unique Id/key will help you to refer any specific data object from the array of records. 
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72735878/javascript-how-to-create-unique-id-on-object-that-is-pushed-into-an-array
https://joshcollinsworth.com/blog/confirm-all-ids-are-unique-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects-using-map-and-sets

I hope this will be helpful.